# .net framework 3.5 and windows 2000 sp4

Tags: windows, .net-3.5

Can we install dotnet framework 3.5 on windows 2000 sp4 or its not possible.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought Windows 2000 was no longer supported? Have you considered upgrading to a supported OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6) says

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows
>   Server 2003; Windows Server 2008;
>   Windows Vista; Windows XP

So it looks like "no".